Problem pulling pre-formatted Base64 from SQL into C#
I am being tasked with pulling base64-encoded image data from a SQL Server database into a C# (Blazor Server .NET 8) application, and embedding the image into the <a> of an html element.
I've already pushed back on base64 being the method of storing the image, and our data infrastructure folks are saying it will not change...
The SQL Server column type for the base64 string is VARCHAR(MAX). The problem I'm running into has to do with encoding upon executing a SELECT query via Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in the .NET back-end.
The string that I get when querying the database directly renders the image perfectly as the src property in an img element, but the string that I'm receiving from the query execution in C# is not. I've tried investigating via base64.guru's decode tool (https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image) and the directly-queried SQL result does decode into the image, while the string I write to Console in the .NET query does not. Using base64.guru's 'Repair Tool', it can be fixed with the repair finding saying "We found the Byte Order Mark" - returning a working base64 string!
I think this has something to do with this BOM(s) being inserted due to C#'s default UTF16 encoding, but I've been completely unable to remove them from the string and get a working image. I've tried the Trim() method, converting to and from byte[], and others with no joy.
Here's my generic code below. The base64 itself is around 6 MB so I can't post the entire result here, but you'll get the picture:
string invoiceNumber = INV12345;
string query = "SELECT invoiceImage FROM dbo.receipts WHERE invoiceNumber = @InvoiceNumber";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceNumber", invoiceNumber);

        try
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();

            var result = await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();

            if (result != null && result != DBNull.Value)
            {
                // Here's the string in question
                string EmbedImage = result.ToString()
                Console.WriteLine(EmbedImage);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invoice image not found for the provided invoice number.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

The base64 string is pulling, so the error handling channels are not being triggered, but like I explained above, the base64 string seems to not be working. Presumably due to one or more BOMs. On visual inspection of the strings (SQL direct query vs .NET query) they beginning and ends seem to be the same, and the rest of it is too large to sift through.
I have tried:

Using the Convert.ToBase64String() method
EmbedImage = Convert.ToBase64String(result.ToString());


Trimming BOM characters:
EmbedImage = result.ToString().Trim(new char[]{'\uFEFF','\u200B'});


Converting to byte array and back
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(result.ToString());
EmbedImage = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);




Can you show us the code that creates the <img> element from the EmbedImage value? What does the generated HTM:L look like (say the leading 50 and trailing 10 characters of the <img> element). it something like: <img src="data:image/gif;base64,xxxxxxxx..xxxxxxxx">?  Drop the xxxxxxxx..xxxxxxxx portion into an editor like Notepad++ and search for regex [^a-zA-Z+/]. The only thing you should find is perhaps one or two "=" at the end and maybe (but unlikely) some optional (non-data) whitespace or newlines. (I am assuming you are using an <img> element inside your <a> element.

Can you make a complete console app that reproduces this against a SQLLocalDb instance ?

A number of possibilities for this sort of issue...

Base64 itself has a number of differing rule-sets/conventions (around termination, separators and "characters 62 and 63"): Wikipedia

Text encoding/decoding and byte order marks BOM: Up to .Net Framework 3.5 string.Trim() would identify BOMs as whitespace and remove them, but since Fx4 you must trim explicitly, specifying the preamble bytes for the encoding, obtained string bomUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble()); and similarly bomUtf16... Unicode.GetPreamble().

Given that your image data is stored using VARCHAR, can you be certain of the convention/s of the system writing the data? If not you may need to write some search-replace code to get this working in C# under all circumstances.



I ended up solving my issue the way that AlanK recommended by explicitly identifying the encoding (UTF16 / Unicode) and getting the preamble trimmed!
For anyone experiencing the same issue
